# How to enforce symmetry in a combination problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The question:

A bike sharing scheme has a row of 12 bays in to which 6 identical bikes are placed at random. An arrangement is the pattern made by the bikes and spaces (ignoring which specific bike is at a specific location). For example, one arrangement is fully described by the below sequence (b means bike, s means space):

```
sbbsbssbsbbs
```

For aesthetic reasons, I would like to know the probability that the arrangement is symmetric. In the sense that if I looked at it from the opposite side, the arrangement would be the same. Put another way, the sequence is a palindrome (it reads the same forwards as backwards). The following sequence is symmetric:

```
bssbbssbbssb
```

We assume that all arrangements are equally likely.

(1) How many symmetric arrangements are there with 6 bikes?

(2) Given that there are 6 bikes in the stand in a random arrangement, what is the probability that this arrangement is symmetric?

I am confused by this question. It seems to me to be a question to do with combinations. I've worked out, I think, that there are 924 ways of arranging the bikes (this number seems quite big I admit...) but I'm not sure how I would enforce this symmetry constraint in terms of the combination formula. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: For the arrangement to be symmetric, you need exactly three bikes in the first $6$ bays. Then the rest of the arrangement is uniquely determined. $924$ is the correct total number of arrangements.

Comment: Yes, just thought that. So I will essentially look at the different ways you can arrange 3 bikes in 6 bays, and then since you can do the same on both sides, your answer for symmetric combinations is just the number of combinations for 3 bikes in 6

Comment: Do you think my initial number is too big (924) for the amount of distinguishable sequences of 6 bikes in 12 bays? I just plugged the numbers in to the combination formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrangement of bikes is specified by choosing the six locations where bikes are, out of the twelve possible locations. Since order does not matter, the total number of arrangements is $$\binom{12}6=\frac{12!}{6!\cdot 6!}=924$$

To choose a symmetric arrangment of bikes, there need to be exactly three bikes in the left half. There are $\binom 63$ ways to choose where the bikes in the left half go. Once the bikes on the left are placed, the bikes on the right can only be placed in one way while ensuring symmetry. Therefore, there are $\binom 63=20$ symmetric arrangements.

The probability of symmetry is therefore $20/924$.